Can i customize OCI Images?
I am using spring bootBuildImage tool for creating docker image and publishing it to the ECR(AWS registry).
But now i want to customise my docker image. Maybe add my custom containerFile or something like that?
More specific i want to add entries to /etc/hosts file in the docker container. I cant add extra_hosts to the container definitions cause its not supported in FARGATE.
Or can i resolve dns hosts some other way?
I tried to add extra_hosts parameter to the ecs container definitions but its not supported in FARGATE.

Are you asking if you can customize the image at build time, or are you asking if you can customize the container at run time? Or something else? Your question is a bit vague. For your specific /etc/hosts problem, you might want to look into using a Route53 private hosted zone in your VPC to customize the DNS resolution of certain addresses from inside your VPC.

In most cases you don't want to edit /etc/hosts at all.  Container environments usually overwrite this file in any case and you can't include it in an image.  In an AWS context, can you set up Route 53 entries to get standard DNS setup?

Thank you very much. Didnt think about route53
